# Java - File Handling for Character File

Tags: java

I have a file with characters like thi: `ABCD...HHCCCCHH..BC`

Now, I want to remove characters between two `H` if gap between two `H` is less than 20 characters. And write the output in a new file. So, the new file will look like this:

`ABCD...HH..BC`

Can this be done in a fast way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file will fit in memory easily, and you can use Apache commons-io.

```
String input = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("inputFile"), "UTF-8");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("H[^H]{1,19}H");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
String output = m.replaceAll("HH");
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("outputFile"), output, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Why does the pattern have `HH` at the beginning and ending? Should it not be `H` instead?

Comment: Good point. Updated. The original wording was confusing, but both the original and the edited version are clearly asking to replace everything between the H's, not between double-H's.

Comment: 20 is an **exclusive** upper bound, but in the regex 20 is inclusive. Better make that 19.

Comment: We have now converged on the same answer, except for the reading and writing files part. There are of course many options for that piece.

Comment: Ooops, I think I made a mistake while making that edit. I assumed the OP meant `H`, not `HH` and he wrote `HH` by mistake. Not sure if I'm right about this yet, I will definitely be more careful in the future.

Comment: ... and mine got downvoted while I was in the kitchen :) So let only yours stay.

Comment: Nope. You got it right. The sample input/output in the original question makes it clear.

Comment: I reviewed the original question, it's definitely not clear what exactly OP wants. He says "between two HHs" and the sample shows that the text between the two occurrences of "HH" has been removed, but only one HH pair stayed in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Pure Java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\data1.txt"));
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    String line=null;
    while((line=in.readLine())!=null)
        sb.append(line);

    String alteredData=sb.toString().replaceAll("H.{1,19}H", "HH");

    BufferedWriter out=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("d:\\data2.txt"));
    out.write(alteredData);

    in.close();
    out.close();

}
```

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik But OP wants to change `ABCD...HHCCCCHH..BC` into `ABCD...HH..BC` so catching inner `H` in `HHCCCCHH` should be ok.

Comment: The OP didn't specify any requirements on the characters between the outer HH's.

Comment: Your pattern can match "HAAHBBH" in its entirety, swallowing the inner H, since it is a greedy match.

Comment: ... it's clearly NOT what OP wants. You may have a creative intepretation of the phrase "gap between two HHs" to cover for your solution, but that doesn't help much.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik In my opinion if it is not greedy match then `HHCCCCHH` cant generate `HH`. OP gave us good example that he doesn't care if there are other `H` between outer `H`s. At least thats how I see it. There is no point in arguing about it anyway. We don't know for 100% what OP wants :)

Comment: That is indeed true, I already commented on it below the other question. However, in all probability there was only a mixup with the number of H's in the output. Bear in mind that OP's original phrasing is "gap between two `HH`s" -- so `HH` is the delimiter, not a single `H`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thank you for telling me that this is not original OP question. I didn't know about it earlier. Now I am sure that our discussion is ... lets say unnecessary :D

Answer (score 1):

I'd have left this as a comment to John Watts' answer, but it's slightly too long...

Buffered I/O is Java is pretty efficient. It's not necessary to load the entire file into memory, to get decent performance. Assuming it's a line-oriented file, and the patterns don't cross line boundaries, this is sufficient:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

...

BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
FileWriter w = new FileWriter(outFile);
String line;
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("HH.{1,19}HH");

while (((line = r.readLine()) != null)
{
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    w.write(m.replaceAll("HHHH"));
    w.write('\n');
}

w.close();
r.close();

...
```